# jQuery stops working in Code, but works in Console (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So i use this code in a template.php of WordPress:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log('A');
    $('div.banner_gebraucht').each(function(){
      console.log('B');
        if( $.trim($(this).text()) == '') {
                    console.log('step info')
            $(this).hide();
            $('.banner3dtriangle_gebraucht').hide();
            console.log('D');
        }
    });
});

 </script>
```

In Console it works, but in the template.php it only outputs A. Can you guys tell me, why this script stops?

Comment: I assume there is no div with class banner_gebraucht at the time of load

Comment: Maybe `div.banner_gebraucht` is added in an asynchrobous way?

Comment: These Div's get loaded by WP Bakery (Custom Grid).. so this could be a problem. Is there any function to force this code only if the whole DOM is loaded? Shouldn't .ready() to this?

Comment: Ask here: https://support.wpbakery.com/ - and no. the document.ready is triggered when all the elements loaded on the page have loaded. It does not know you triggered something else async

Answer (score 0):

So the elements you need have not loaded at the time of document.ready.

Try this if you cannot attach to a load of the grid

```js
var tId;
function hideBanners() {
  var $banners = $('div.banner_gebraucht');
  if ($banners.length == 0) {
    tId = setTimeout(hidebanners, 1000);
    return;
  }
  $banners.each(function() {
    console.log('B');
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == '') {
      console.log('step info')
      $(this).hide();
      $('.banner3dtriangle_gebraucht').hide();
      console.log('D');
    }
  });

}
$(function() {
  console.log('A');
  hideBanners();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: (delete old answer, irrelevant for question, because jQuery comes preinstalled in wordpress, so it should be loaded.)

Comment: suggestion and queries should be posted in the comment. Not in the answer.

Comment: thanks, you're right. will update the answer.

Comment: This is obviously not the problem since console shows `A`

Comment: Used ur code. Still only shows A. I'm sorry. Did not downvote you btw. Also: You missed "});" at the end.

Comment: Is the div present when the DOM is ready or will it be loaded from an external source? thanks for "})", the answer should show what to fix.

Comment: It gets loaded by WP Bakery (Post Grid). Its a custom Grid i made in Grid Builder. So it gets loaded from an external source.

Comment: so @mplungjan is right. The issue is because the div is not loaded at time of execution of this script.

Comment: Its the only thing i could think of.. but now would be the question: how to execute after the full DOM is loaded? Stuff like: $(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
}); did not work :(

Comment: try $(".banner_gebraucht").load(function(){ // do stuff here });